# Baby bottles accidentally steamed with soft plastic teether - melted - Bottles still safe?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I'm not sure who to ask so have been googling around -- My husband accidentally steamed our new teether for our infant son with the bottles. What he didn't remember/realize is that you're not supposed to (per the package notes) and found out quickly why when he opened the steamer and the plastic was molten and the gel on the bottom of our steamer. My concern is: I can wash and re-steam our bottles, nipples, bottle parts (some plastic), but should we be worried about some kind of chemical reaction that happened within the bubble of the steamer? I am not well enough versed in chemistry to know if this would be a problem. I'm just about out of bottles for the day so I'm hoping someone has the answer somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. I understand your predicament, but personal medical questions (and this one does fit the category) are off-topic on Chemistry. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation as it is impossible to judge. For example, we would need to know the exact composition of everything in the bath to exclude any evil reaction...